# GETUTCDATE() return null

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, triggers

I have trigger after Insert that update field in the table with  GETUTCDATE() but after Insertion I see the value = null

```
SET NOCOUNT ON 
UPDATE [dbo].[Employee] 
SET [CurrentDate] = GETUTCDATE() 
FROM inserted 
WHERE inserted.[Id] = [dbo].[Employee].[Id]
```

Comment: Would you be able to tell us what variant of SQL this is being performed in?

Comment: U mean the version sql server 2008 R2

Comment: Why are you using an after insert trigger for this rather than a default constraint anyway? But it works fine. [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/93994/1). Please include code that reproduces the issue.

Comment: And as **there is nothing actually wrong with the code in the question** it would be good if people stopped posting random guesses until it is clarified.

Answer (score -1):

Try using the INNER JOIN statement and see if it works, i.e.

```
UPDATE [dbo].[Employee] 
SET [CurrentDate] = GETUTCDATE() 
FROM dbo.Employee 
INNER JOIN inserted  ON inserted.[Id] = [dbo].[Employee].[Id]
```

...it may not like the join condition in the where clause